# Is there an algorithm or protocol that allows to securely generate random shuffles when two parties are not colluding without a sever side seed?

Tags: random-number-generator, randomness

I am building an app that pits one party against another party in a gambling transaction – both parties have competing interests and have an incentive not to cheat the other party.

I am looking for a cryptographic solution for this.  It includes card games but not Poker (so this includes baccarat, blackjack, and other games including some dice games).  Mental Poker is a solution similar to what I am after, but mental poker, as I understand it, either cannot be applied to games like this or should not… although I don't see why not (other than the increased computational issues)?

But the idea where you can encrypt a deck of cards (or the combinations of two dice) and pass that to shuffle is still along the line of what I am after since this method does not require a central sever to provide a seed to a local application and can still provide a pseudo random outcome.

Comment: It is not very clear what are you asking for. The title caim you are looking for a PRNG - every system or application environment provides some sort of "SecureRandom".  Or do you seek help with the use case itself (like e.g. [commitment scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_scheme)) . I think you should ask only a one question at the time.

Comment: I am looking for an algorithm  or process that would allow an app to securely generate a random shuffle when two parties are not colluding with out a sever side seed.  I want to remove the server seed from the process and have the clients handling generating the random outcome - of course this can create risks, since Apps can be attacked..so it needs to be secured, random and provably fair.

Comment: If I understand your desires: both sides generate their own random bits, commit to the random value via cryptographic bit commitment, and reveal their strings to each other (cheaters will be detected due to the commit).  The xor of those values should suffice for the seed.

Comment: I understand about pre-committing and using a hash function for provably fair, but this isn't the problem here the point of this project to to remove the server and still have a secure random outcome generated between at least two disinterested parties.....so three additional questions:

Comment: 1) how do you recommend generating the seed on the client app (there wont be a server, its all P-2-P);  2) what PRNG do you suggest; and, 3) is this process safe from someone decompiling the app or using some sort of sniffing algo to detect the seed/seeding process to corrupt the game?  Normally you keep an RNG in a secure server to protect the integrity of the seeding and RNG process, but I want something totally decentralized that is equally secure as a server based RNG for card and dice games where you can roll dice or show all cards (unlike poker where you hide some cards).

Comment: I believe I understand now. You expect a client to provide some values (like cards with 4 Aces) and how can another client trust that the values are trully random? well - I believe the easiest way would be really some random dealer (server service)

Comment: Yes!  But I don't want a server! :) There is the problem - if you use Mental Poker (in Poker) you can avoid a server as long as you have competing interests since the deck gets encrypted (I also have at least 2 parties who are competitive at all times).  As I understand that process, cards are placed in a variable from 0-51 then sent encrypted to another player who shuffles encrypted deck  (but I don't know how the shuffle is seeded) - if that works for Mental Poker and no server is required, then surely there is a solution using cryptology for a simpler problem that I am trying to understand.